# Cambiar imagen de botón con drawable

Tags: android, android-button

Tengo tres gráficos xml para tres tipos de botones.

Estoy elaborando un pequeño Quiz en Android y he diseñado los xml antes mencionados para evaluar las respuestas y mostrar de un color el boton según la respuesta.

`boton_redondo`: Por default para todos los botones

`boton_redondo_error`: Si es errónea la respuesta

`boton_redondo_correcto`: Si es correcta la respuesta

El problema es que no encuentro cual es la instrucción correcta para cambiar el color al boton al hacer clic. Estoy intentando con esto:

```
r1.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));
```

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme con esto?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el `OnTouchListener` es lo mismo que usar el `OnClickListener` solo que este hará algo cuando lo toques solamente. te dejo la documentación [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, encontre la solución usando esto:
'''r1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));'''

Comment: @JoseDanielSolis Te sugiero usar setBackgroundResource() en lugar de setBackgroundDrawable() ya que este método es obsoleto desde la API 16

Answer (score 3):

Usa `setBackgroundResource()` que es una forma más corta donde defines únicamente el id de la imagen :

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error);
```

---

Método obsoleto a partir de API 16:

<strike>Para cambiar la imagen, simplemente usa [`setBackgroundDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))</strike> donde tienes que obtener el `Drawable` de la imagen a partir del recurso:

```
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));
```